# How to define the number of factors in parallel analysis

Tags: factor-analysis, paf

I conducted an Exploratory Factor Analysis (Principal Axis Factoring) on my data and wanted to determine the number of factors to extract via. Horn's Parallel Analysis.

However I have two problems:

1. The parallel analysis suggests to extract 1 factor, however the plot shows more than one intersection of my "FA Actual Data" and my "FA Simulated Data" line. I do not get why it is just one factor (the first intersection) then.... This plot does not look typical to other parallel analysis plots.
2. Why does the number of factors to extract change with the number of observations (n.obs) I state? I mean that I just changed the number of observations from 50 to 500 (which is a lie), however then parallel analysis suggested 5 factors to extract instead of 9. I do not get why....

Thank you so much for any helpful tips. 
Valerie

fa.parallel(cor(My_Data), n.obs = 50, fa="fa", fm="pa")

> Parallel analysis suggests that the number of factors =  1  and the number of components =  NA

Comment: Sorry, I meant "... 5 factors to extract instead of 1" above